# Public and Private keys incorrect for user

Tags: php, ssh, wordpress

I've followed [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-secure-updates-and-installations-in-wordpress-on-ubuntu) (which worked for me on several VPS's) to configure a secure way to install and update themes and plugins in Wordpress. Basically:

```
sudo adduser wp-user
cd /var/www
sudo chown -R wp-user:wp-user /var/www/
sudo su - wp-user
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096
exit
sudo chown wp-user:www-data /home/wp-user/wp_rsa*
sudo chmod 0640 /home/wp-user/wp_rsa*
sudo mkdir /home/wp-user/.ssh
sudo chown wp-user:wp-user /home/wp-user/.ssh/
sudo chmod 0700 /home/wp-user/.ssh/
sudo cp /home/wp-user/wp_rsa.pub /home/wp-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
sudo chown wp-user:wp-user /home/wp-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
sudo chmod 0644 /home/wp-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
sudo nano /home/wp-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

> from="127.0.0.1" ssh-rsa...

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5-dev libssh2-1-dev libssh2-php
sudo nano /var/www/wp-config.php
```

Add:

```
define('FTP_PUBKEY','/home/wp-user/wp_rsa.pub');
define('FTP_PRIKEY','/home/wp-user/wp_rsa');
define('FTP_USER','wp-user');
define('FTP_PASS','');
define('FTP_HOST','127.0.0.1:22');
```

And finally:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

For some reason, I'm getting the message:

> Public and Private keys incorrect for wp-user

Looking for an answer, I've seen [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/396886/wordpress-cant-find-ssh-public-and-private-key-pair), but none of the answers has worked for me.

First, I put the files into `/home/wp-user` directory, but also tried into `/home/wp-user/.ssh`. This is what I have right now:

```
ls -la /home/wp-user/.ssh

drwx------ 2 wp-user wp-user  4096 Mar  1 15:02 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 wp-user wp-user  4096 Mar  1 14:58 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 wp-user wp-user   742 Mar  1 15:02 authorized_keys
-rw-r----- 1 wp-user www-data 3247 Mar  1 14:58 wp_rsa
-rw-r----- 1 wp-user www-data  742 Mar  1 14:58 wp_rsa.pub
```

And:

```
define('FTP_PUBKEY','/home/wp-user/.ssh/wp_rsa.pub');
define('FTP_PRIKEY','/home/wp-user/.ssh/wp_rsa');
define('FTP_USER','wp-user');
define('FTP_PASS','');
define('FTP_HOST','127.0.0.1:miCustomPortForSSH');
```

I can see this output on `auth.log` each time I try to connect:

```
Mar  1 14:37:51 vpsxxxx sshd[2430]: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj to -800
Mar  1 14:37:51 vpsxxxx sshd[2430]: Connection from 127.0.0.1 port 56103
Mar  1 14:37:51 vpsxxxx sshd[2430]: Received disconnect from 127.0.0.1: 11: PECL/ssh2 (http://pecl.php.net/packages/ssh2) [preauth]
```

with different port each time:

```
Mar  1 14:38:16 vpsxxxx sshd[2435]: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj to -800
Mar  1 14:38:16 vpsxxxx sshd[2435]: Connection from 127.0.0.1 port 56128
Mar  1 14:38:16 vpsxxxx sshd[2435]: Received disconnect from 127.0.0.1: 11: PECL/ssh2 (http://pecl.php.net/packages/ssh2) [preauth]
```

I'm using Apache2 and Nginx as proxy server, but log files doesn't reveal anything. Any idea?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: No, I don't. Still using FTP :(

Comment: Hey, I just solved my issue and answered it here. Hope it helps. If you need more assistance I'm more than happy to help. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/194529/public-and-private-keys-are-incorrect-for-user/195781#195781

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the private key is too open as it is group readable. Try removing the group read permissions

```
chmod g-r wp_rsa
```

and see how that goes.

Comment: Done it, but nothing changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the **php_admin_value open_basedir** directive at all, the keys need to be in a directory that is included in the paths listed.

Answer (score 1):

On two Debian 10 servers I had to add `-m PEM` parameter to ssh-keygen.

Otherwise the key worked when I used SSH from terminal, but it didn't work in Wordpress, resulting in the same disconnect message like the one that appeared in your log. Instead, `ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa` worked without any problem.

Also, I had to enable `allow_url_fopen = On` in PHP, otherwise Wordpress could not find wp-content directory.

Answer (score 0):

First poster is half right.  SSH will reject your private key if it's readable by anything other than the owner group.  However if the wp-user is the owner and only the owner can read the private key, then the server can't read it and you can't use the web-interface.  Therefore you have to change the owner on both the public an private key.  Here's how you fix this.

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data /home/wp-user/wp_rsa*
sudo chmod 600 /home/wp-user/wp_rsa
```

In defense of the author of the post you followed, that post was written for Ubuntu 12.04 and I know in my case I have a 14.04 install.

Also, the installation of the extra libraries and the modifications to the wp-config.php file are unnecessary on Ubuntu 14.04 and Wordpress v4.2.2 just FYI.

Comment: If the user to use to upgrade is specified in the wp-config and it's the same who has the permission to read the keys, why then should the www-data user allowed to read the key?

Comment: Because the server is the one that needs to read the key in this case, even though it's the wp-user that's logging in.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using www-data as owner, adding the following line to wp-config.php solved it for me.

```
define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct' );
```

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same error message. @Manolo wasn't using a passphrase in the original question, but I was. I was able to get it to work after I generated ssh keys without a passphrase.

According to https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Enabling_SSH_Upgrade_Access "It is recommended to use a private key that is not pass-phrase protected. There have been numerous reports that pass phrase protected private keys do not work properly."

Comment: Seems you have a different problem, then.